# Determinant Formulae for Wedge Products

Tags: exterior-algebra

In $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, consider k
  covectors $\mathbf{E}_{i_{1}},...,\mathbf{E}_{i_{k}}$
  chosen from the standard dual basis of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$
 , where $k\in\mathbb{N}$
  is arbitrary. Then, $\mathbf{E}_{i_{1}}\wedge\mathbf{E}_{i_{2}}\wedge...\wedge\mathbf{E}_{i_{k}}$
  is in $\textrm{Alt}^{k}\left(\mathbb{R}^{n}\right)$
  (it is an alternating k
  form); it accepts k
  vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$
  as input, and is given by the formula:$\left(\mathbf{E}_{i_{1}}\wedge\mathbf{E}_{i_{2}}\wedge...\wedge\mathbf{E}_{i_{k}}\right)\left(\mathbf{v}_{1},...,\mathbf{v}_{k}\right)=\textrm{det}\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
\mathbf{E}_{i_{1}}\left(\mathbf{v}_{1}\right) & \mathbf{E}_{i_{1}}\left(\mathbf{v}_{2}\right) & \cdots & \mathbf{E}_{i_{1}}\left(\mathbf{v}_{k}\right)\\
\mathbf{E}_{i_{2}}\left(\mathbf{v}_{1}\right) & \mathbf{E}_{i_{2}}\left(\mathbf{v}_{2}\right) & \cdots & \mathbf{E}_{i_{2}}\left(\mathbf{v}_{k}\right)\\
\vdots &  & \ddots\\
\mathbf{E}_{i_{k}}\left(\mathbf{v}_{1}\right) & \mathbf{E}_{i_{k}}\left(\mathbf{v}_{2}\right) & \cdots & \mathbf{E}_{i_{k}}\left(\mathbf{v}_{k}\right)
\end{array}\right)$

I take this expression as the definition of the wedge product of the above covectors.

Now, let $\ell\in\mathbb{N}$ be arbitrary, let $\alpha=\mathbf{E}_{i_{1}}\wedge\mathbf{E}_{i_{2}}\wedge...\wedge\mathbf{E}_{i_{k}}$ be the form from above, and let $\beta=\mathbf{E}_{j_{1}}\wedge\mathbf{E}_{j_{2}}\wedge...\wedge\mathbf{E}_{j_{\ell}}$ be a form given by the wedge product of $\ell$ standard dual basis covectors. I know that $\alpha\wedge\beta\in\textrm{Alt}^{k+\ell}\left(\mathbb{R}^{n}\right)$. What is the formula for $\left(\alpha\wedge\beta\right)\left(\mathbf{v}_{1},...,\mathbf{v}_{k},\mathbf{w}_{1},...,\mathbf{w}_{\ell}\right)$
 written as a determinant in the manner of the formula given above for $\alpha$
 ?

(Please write the answer as a the determinant of a matrix in the manner used above, no abbreviations. And no patronizing for me wanting a simple formula with respect to a given basis. Thank you.)

Comment: I read somewhere terms are in bijection with the various "interleavings" of the **v** and **w** vectors as if one where shuffling a deck of cards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it would be the same formula (only with the indexes appropriately modified)! Namely,

$$(\alpha \wedge \beta)\left(\mathbf{v}_{1},...,\mathbf{v}_{k}, \mathbf{w}_{1},...,\mathbf{w}_{l}\right) =
\\ \textrm{det}\left(\begin{array}{cccccccc}
\mathbf{E}_{i_{1}}\left(\mathbf{v}_{1}\right) & \mathbf{E}_{i_{1}}\left(\mathbf{v}_{2}\right) & \cdots & \mathbf{E}_{i_{1}}\left(\mathbf{v}_{k}\right) & \mathbf{E}_{i_1}(\mathbf{w}_1) & \cdots & \mathbf{E}_{i_1}(\mathbf{w}_l) \\
\mathbf{E}_{i_{2}}\left(\mathbf{v}_{1}\right) & \mathbf{E}_{i_{2}}\left(\mathbf{v}_{2}\right) & \cdots & \mathbf{E}_{i_{2}}\left(\mathbf{v}_{k}\right) & \mathbf{E}_{i_2}(\mathbf{w}_1) & \cdots & \mathbf{E}_{i_2}(\mathbf{w}_l) \\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\mathbf{E}_{i_{k}}\left(\mathbf{v}_{1}\right) & \mathbf{E}_{i_{k}}\left(\mathbf{v}_{2}\right) & \cdots & \mathbf{E}_{i_{k}}\left(\mathbf{v}_{k}\right) & \mathbf{E}_{i_k}(\mathbf{w}_1) & \cdots & \mathbf{E}_{i_k}(\mathbf{w}_l) \\
\mathbf{E}_{j_{1}}\left(\mathbf{v}_{1}\right) & \mathbf{E}_{j_{1}}\left(\mathbf{v}_{2}\right) & \cdots & \mathbf{E}_{j_{1}}\left(\mathbf{v}_{k}\right) & \mathbf{E}_{j_1}(\mathbf{w}_1) & \cdots & \mathbf{E}_{j_1}(\mathbf{w}_l) \\
\mathbf{E}_{j_{2}}\left(\mathbf{v}_{1}\right) & \mathbf{E}_{j_{2}}\left(\mathbf{v}_{2}\right) & \cdots & \mathbf{E}_{j_{2}}\left(\mathbf{v}_{k}\right) & \mathbf{E}_{j_2}(\mathbf{w}_1) & \cdots & \mathbf{E}_{j_2}(\mathbf{w}_l) \\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\mathbf{E}_{j_{l}}\left(\mathbf{v}_{1}\right) & \mathbf{E}_{j_{l}}\left(\mathbf{v}_{2}\right) & \cdots & \mathbf{E}_{j_{l}}\left(\mathbf{v}_{k}\right) & \mathbf{E}_{j_l}(\mathbf{w}_1) & \cdots & \mathbf{E}_{j_l}(\mathbf{w}_l) \\
\end{array}\right).$$

Comment: Thanks for saving me the trouble of typing out a (more abbreviated) version of this.

Comment: @TedShifrin: Yeah, I was wondering whether I should just write "it is the same formula!" but thought that might sound a bit "patronizing".

Comment: With all the abstract definitions in terms of skew-symmetrizing tensor products and throwing in factorials, it's not obvious that it's so simple. :)

Comment: 1) Thank you so much.
2) No, it is not the same formula. The symbols are different. Two formulae are the same if and only if they contain _exactly_ the same symbols in exactly the same format and spatial arrangement. ;)

Comment: Does this formula also work for the wedge products of multi-vectors (vectors, bivectors, trivectors, etc.)? Do you just take duals everywhere—capitalize the lower case letters and lower case the capital letters?

Comment: @MSC: If I understand you correctly, then no. The general formula of $\alpha \wedge \beta$ if $\alpha,\beta$ that are not necessarily of the form $E_{i_1} \wedge \dots \wedge E_{i_k}$ in terms of $\alpha,\beta$ is more complicated to write but you can always write $\alpha,\beta$ as a linear combinations of terms as above and then use the formula provided in the answer.